# Android Facebook sdk, encrypt photo when uploading

Tags: android, facebook

The question is about security consideration for an android app I am developing. I am able to upload photos to facebook, using Request.newUploadPhotoRequest and then executeAndWait. But i would like to the photos to be transferred in encrypted form. Is it possible ?

i am using facebook sdk 3.

Also, i am not sure, if encryption is done by facebook sdk automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the Request class uses the "https" scheme, so the standard SSL encryption applies.